# How to Import Google Drive Sub-Folder URL to Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import the Sub-folder's (Not Files) Name & URL which is in the Main Folder to Google Sheets

[image]

I tried working on this code but it didn't help me to achieve my task.

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
    
   
    function getFolderArray(folderId){
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      var Folders = folder.getFolders();
      var FolderList = [];
      
      //Loop though Folders and add names and urls to the array
      while (folder.hasNext()){ 
        var Folder = Folders.next();
        var FolderName = Folder.getName();    
        var FolderUrl = Folder.getUrl();
        FolderList = FolderList.concat([[FolderName, FolderUrl]]);
      }
       //See returned FolderList in a log
      //Logger.log( FolderList ) //Preview Returned Array      
      return FolderList
      
     
    }
    
      
    //Prints any 2D array to a range that starts with the selected cell
    function printArrayToSelection(twoDimArr){  
      var firstCell = SS.getActiveCell();
      var lastCell = firstCell.offset(twoDimArr.length - 1, twoDimArr[0].length - 1);
      var destinationRange = SS.getActiveSheet().getRange(
        firstCell.getA1Notation() + ':' + lastCell.getA1Notation());
      destinationRange.setValues(twoDimArr);
      
    }
    
    //Print the actual data
    function printFolderArray(){
      printArrayToSelection(getFolderArray('0B4-wws2P3gUhcExqWEI0VTlrNm8'));
    }
```

Can I know what went wrong?

Comment: If you want to handle folders, not files, then instead of using `folder.getFiles()`, use a [`FolderIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator). For each folder you can get the URL (using [`getUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getUrl())) and the name.

Comment: @andrewjames I amended as you suggested, but i'm getting a error message Exception: Invalid argument: id getFolderArray @ Code.gs:10

Comment: OK - but you understand the general point I was trying to make in my comment? You were using the wrong tool for the job. Now you tried to use the right tool - but in the wrong way. And finally, the answer shows how to use the right tool in one right way. But the starting point is to look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) - and to notice that there are methods for handling files - and _different_ methods for handling folders. It's perfectly OK to need help about how to use those methods, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function listOfFoldersByID() {
  var folderid = '_______your folder ID___________'; // change FolderID
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clear();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(["parent","folder","URL"]);
  try {
    var parentFolder =DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
    listSubFolders(parentFolder,parentFolder.getName());
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}

function listSubFolders(parentFolder,parent) {
  var childFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow([parent,childFolder.getName(),childFolder.getUrl()]);
    listSubFolders(childFolder,parent + "|" + childFolder.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a coder but I see there is no Folder ID to recognize from which folder the SUB FOLDER should be URL should be taken from. ???

Comment: Yes, I give you all the folders ... I will introduce the ID of the parent folder

Comment: Sorry for my poor coding skills, I didn't understand what you've trying say? :(

Comment: I tried to amend the variation with DriveApp.getFolderById("0B-wws2P3gUhcExqWEI0VTl8"); but I got the error TypeError: subfolder.hasNext is not a function
listerOfFolders @ Code.gs:7

Comment: I modified my answer. Make sure your ID is the ID of a folder